# Vaadin 7, JPA 2 and form binding

Tags: jpa, vaadin

I have two DB tables and corresponding Entity classes:-

### EXAM Class

```
Entity
@Table(name="exam", schema="xyz")
...
private int examid;
private String examname;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="startedby")    
private User startedByUser;

...

public String getStartedByName() {
        if (startedByUser != null){
            return (startedByUser.getDesign()+' '+startedByUser.getFname()+' '+startedByUser.getLname()).trim();
        }else{      
            return "N/A";
        }
}

...
```

### USER Class

```
Entity
@Table(name="user", schema="xyz")
...
private int userid;
private String username;
private String fname;
private String lname;

...
```

When i try and bind these to a Vaadin form and open an existing exam with the startedByUser set, it all works as expected and i can display the user who started the exam.

```
startedByName = (TextField) fieldGroup.buildAndBind("STARTED BY", "startedByName");
```

However, if this is a new exam, the startedBy user will be null until someone hits the 'started' button. The onClick handler for this button should set the startedByUser value to the current user (i hold this in a local user object) and the form should display the startedByName value accordingly.

I don't seem to be able to set this using the form, which leaves me a big problem.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

I know i can do the following:-

```
examItem.getItemProperty("startedByUser").setValue(user);
```

But this means the form is not in control of the commit.

John.

Answer (score -1):

For now, i have used a combobox which is bound to the form. This way, i can set the userno and the combobox updates with the corresponding user name. Not sure if this is the best option?